# Same styling across multiple components in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, scss-mixins

I have multiple(around 6) components (HTML) having the same styling like

`<headertag>Some Content</headertag> <headertag>Some subtitle</headertag> Here there might be different content or svg/img or input fields. <button>accept</button> <button>cancel</button>`

How Can I add a common style for this situation.

For ex: Each stylesheet will have.
`h2 { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 30px; color: Blue; }  button { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`

How do I remove the repetitive styles from each stylesheet. We are using scss.
Any tips please
Thanks

I was thinking about mixins but felt it is not a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Base Stylesheet" -> If the styles are very common across multiple components, you can create a base stylesheet that contains these common styles. Then, import this base stylesheet into your component stylesheets.

```css
// this is in file: _base.scss
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: blue;
}
button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

And in your component where you want to use the base style SCSS:

```css
@import 'base';
```

Hope this is the one you was looking for. Have a nice day

Comment: Or you can use the `styles.scss`. In angular.json, you have an array of "scss" that it's global to all the aplication. You can use this file. Tip, if you don't want to all the aplication also to a few components, enclosed each components in a div with class "especial" and use a more specific css, e.g. `special h1{margin-top: 0}`

Comment: There are many ways you can do it. The problem is which one to choose. At this point, I thing Nidhi will need to dig deeper to choose the correct path, which solves the problem best for his specific situation.

Comment: Please be aware that due to the way in which style encapsulation works this approach may end up causing application bloat as an encapsulated set of styles would be created for each import of the _base.scss partial.

Comment: I'm not sure but It seems this approach leads to css duplication for each of the components exporting it. stackoverflow.com/a/41491281/4572561 Does AOT compiler strip it?

And which approach would be better in comparison then ?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach not already mentioned here is that Angular components are able to accept an array of stylesheets:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'info-dialog',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [CommonModule],
    templateUrl: './info-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./info-dialog.component.scss', '../styles/dialogs.scss'],
})
```

In the simple example above, styles unique to the `info-dialog` component can be maintained independently of a common shared stylesheet for all dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `host` property of `@Component` selector and add a common class for all the components, then in the global styles you can add.

global_styles.css

```
.common-changes h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: Blue;
}
.common-changes button {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  color: Blue;
}
```

child component - one of multiple

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  template: `
  <h2 >Some Content</h2 > 
  <h2 >Some subtitle</h2 > 
  Here there might be different content or svg/img or input fields. 
  <button>accept</button> 
  <button>cancel</button>
  `,
  host: {
    class: 'common-changes',
  },
  standalone: true,
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cbtd1m?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fc%2Fc.component.ts,src%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts,src%2Fa%2Fa.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)